# Can I specify a different email for the StackDriver Error Reporting Notification

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

We tried to use the StackDriver Error Reporting notification features, but it seems that for any Project, when we turn on the notification, it always sent to the email associated with the developer account that we logged in. How can we change it to a different email account. (we use PageDuty, and we want this notification to send to a pagerduty sink email account)

Comment: As mentioned at this time this isn't supported. For anyone stopping by; it would be great to star the issue on GCP's end to enable this capability: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116353574

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today, email notifications on new errors for a given project are enabled per user and can only be delivered to the email associated with his user's account.

As a workaround, and if possible, you could setup an email filter that would forward these emails.

I am the Stackdriver Error Reporting product manager.
It is not the first time we hear this feedback and we are working on improving the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, on a side note, we are also using StackDriver for Uptime check? Is there any plan to add a RESTFUL API for creating the Uptime check other than in the UI, we are setting up a multi tenant environment, will have different entry point for each tenant, will love to have the ability to automate this instead of manually creating the Uptime check.

Comment: I have setup an Alerting service when my API goes down, but I dont seem to get any email from StackDriver. I followed all tutorials but its not working still

Comment: @Steren, by reading Google Cloud documentation on Notifications (https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications) it seems that this is still not possible. Could you please confirm?

Comment: > "Email notifications are sent to the email address associated with your Google account. It is not possible to configure a custom email alias (for instance, a team email alias)."
So no, I dont think so

Comment: This response was from 2016, has anything changed? I still can't find this functionality./